# Можно ли получить вывод с .bat файла?

Tags: windows, bat

У меня есть .bat файл с таким кодом: `powershell -ep -C [guid]::NewGuid().Guid`
можно ли как-то получить вывод? Т.е я запускаю батник и получить вывод(ответ на эту команду) и записать ее например в файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В командной строке:

```
myfile.bat > filename.txt
```

Comment: А можно это как-то не из командой строки писать, а из другого bat файла например?

Comment: А почему бы и нет